# How do I make Jackson's build() method pretty-print its JSON output?

Tags: json, spring, jersey, jackson, pretty-print

I use Spring, Jersey and Jackson to provide an API that produces JSON.

My @Component has a @Get method that returns Response.ok(entity).build().

That output is very compact.  How do I make that output pretty / formatted?

Comment: I had a similar question for which I posted the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541757/when-using-spring-mvc-for-rest-how-do-you-enable-jackson-to-pretty-print-rendere/6541956#6541956 HTH!