# Formatting JSON before writing to File

Tags: java, json, jackson

Currently I'm using the [Jackson JSON Processor](https://web.archive.org/web/20150315020718/http://jackson.codehaus.org/) to write preference data and whatnot to files mainly because I want advanced users to be able to modify/backup this data. Jackson is awesome for this because its incredibly easy to use and, apparently performs decently (see [here](http://code.google.com/p/thrift-protobuf-compare/wiki/Benchmarking)), however the only problem I seem to be having with it is when I run `myObjectMapper.writeValue(myFile, myJsonObjectNode)` it writes all of the data in the `ObjectNode` to one line. What I would like to do is to format the JSON into a more user friendly format.

For example, if I pass a simple json tree to it, it will write the following:

```
{"testArray":[1,2,3,{"testObject":true}], "anotherObject":{"A":"b","C":"d"}, "string1":"i'm a string", "int1": 5092348315}
```

I would want it to show up in the file as:

```
{
    "testArray": [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        {
            "testObject": true
        }
    ],
    "anotherObject": {
        "A": "b",
        "C": "d"
    },
    "string1": "i'm a string",
    "int1": 5092348315
}
```

Is anyone aware of a way I could do this with Jackson, or do I have to get the String of JSON from Jackson and use another third party lib to format it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try creating Object Writer like  this

```
 ObjectWriter writer = mapper.defaultPrettyPrintingWriter();
```

Comment: ...wow. I thought I searched through the javadocs of every single function in ObjectMapper thoroughly. I can't believe I missed this. And I actually couldnt find `mapper.defaultPrettyPrintingWriter()` but found it actually as `mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The function mismatch could be due to different versions. I'm using Jackson 2.0.2.

Comment: `mapper.defaultPrettyPrintingWriter()` is actually deprecated in Jackson 1.9.2

Comment: Jackson version 2.15.2: mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()

Answer (score 4):

You need to configure the mapper beforehand as follows:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
mapper.writeValue(myFile, myJsonObjectNode);
```

Answer (score 4):

To enable standard indentation in Jackson 2.0.2 and above use the following:

```
ObjectMapper myObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
myObjectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
myObjectMapper.writeValue(myFile, myJsonObjectNode)
```

> source:https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind

Answer (score 2):

As per above mentioned comments this worked for me very well,

```
     Object json = mapper.readValue(content, Object.class);
     mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(json);
```

Where **content** is your JSON string response

Jackson version:2.12