# JSON pretty-print without changing the order

Tags: java, json, gson

I use `json-simple` and want to have pretty-print for debugging purposes.

Here is a very relavant SO question: [Pretty-Print JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105795/pretty-print-json-in-java)

However the answer in the given thread, not only fixes the indentation but also changes the order of the items to [a ... z] using the string order of the keys.

Is there any way to fix the indentation without changing the order of the items in my JSONObject?

Example:

```
JSONObject myJSon = new JSONObject();
myJSon.put("zzz", 1);
myJSon.put("aaa", 1);

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
System.out.println( gson.toJson(myJSon) );
```

Output:

```
{
  "aaa": 1,
  "zzz": 1
}
```

Desired output:

```
{
  "zzz": 1,
  "aaa": 1
}
```

Edit: I'm using: org.json.simple.JSONObject

Comment: See if this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541757/when-using-spring-mvc-for-rest-how-do-you-enable-jackson-to-pretty-print-render/6541956#6541956

Comment: @carl-lopez What does something about Jackson have to do with Gson?

Comment: Can be replaced with, as you could think

Comment: To the OP: You can't short of modifying the source for Gson (or writing your own printing code). That's part of "pretty printing".

Comment: What is the JSONObject class? Is it com.google.gson.JsonObject class?

Comment: @MichałZiober, `org.json.simple.JSONObject`

Comment: Erm, you're using two completely different JSON parsing libraries; why? The only reason this is even working is because `org.json.simple.JSONObject` extends `HashMap`. (Good eye @MichałZiober - I missed that).

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSONObject : Why JSONObject changing the order of attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229418/jsonobject-why-jsonobject-changing-the-order-of-attributes)

Answer (score 9):

`org.json.simple.JSONObject` class extends `java.util.HashMap` and this is the reason why you see this order of the properties on output. `setPrettyPrinting()` method doesn't change the order. You can remove it from source code and nothing change. If you want to keep the order you can use `java.util.LinkedHashMap` instead of `org.json.simple.JSONObject`.

Simple example:

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public class GsonProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Integer> myJSon = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
        myJSon.put("zzz", 1);
        myJSon.put("aaa", 1);

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(myJSon));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having problems to download and edit the source codes of simple-json using Maven. Any further reading?

Comment: Why do you want to change the library? This is not a solution. Why you do not want to change your source code? Can you show to us your real source code?

Comment: My source code has nothing fancy. Only many JJSONArrays and SONObjects inside other JSONObjects. It is why I was considering to change the library. What you mean by saying 'This is not a solution.' I thought changing `HashMap` to `LinkedHashMap` in the original implementation of `simple-json` would solve the issue. Do you mean it is not a best practice or do you mean it is not going work at all?

Comment: You have to change JSONObjects into LinkedHashMap in your source code. I can't believe that you have so many JSONObjects that easier will be change library than your source code. If you want to change library - OK, it will be working, but is really problematic. How many instances of JSONObjects you have in your source code?Replacing is really easy because LinkedHashMap has "put" method too. So you have to change only the type of object.

Answer (score 0):

No. `JSONObject` is a `HashMap`, there is no order maintained of the entries you `put` into it.