# How to get pretty formatted output from RestTemplate?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, postman, resttemplate, pretty-print

Below is my response from one of the server call from my Spring Boot app,

```
String result = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class).getBody();
```

Then I am returning to client like,

```
return ResponseEntity.ok().body(result);
```

In postman I see json is printed with many `\"` rather pretty formated.

Is there I need to change in response side to see pretty formatted output in Postman?

Sample Postman output:

```
"{\"records\":[{\"pkg_name\":\"com.company.app\",\"start_time\":1580307656040,\"update_time\":12345,\"min\":0.0,\"create_time\":1580307714254,\"time_offset\":21600000,\"datauuid\":\"xyz\",\"max\":0.0,\"heart_beat_count\":1,\"end_time\":1580307656040,\"heart_rate\":91.0,\"deviceuuid\":\"abc\"}]}" ...
```

Expected output: Pretty formatted without `\"`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541757/when-using-spring-mvc-for-rest-how-do-you-enable-jackson-to-pretty-print-render

Comment: @pvpkiran actually I want to remove `\"` how to do so? Updated the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that `String result = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class).getBody();` returns double encoded json string. to unescape and get normal json

```
 String unwrappedJSON = objectMapper.readValue(result, String.class);
 return ResponseEntity.ok().body(unwrappedJSON);
```

EDIT

if result is normal json and not double escaped than you can try:

```
JsonNode result = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, JsonNode.class).getBody();

return ResponseEntity.ok().body(result);
```

Comment: What is object mapper?

Comment: just @Autowire it   `@Autowired ObjectMapper objectMapper;`

Comment: tried with `result = (new ObjectMapper()).readValue(result, String.class);` didn't help though

Comment: can you print `result` before send

Comment: before this line `return ResponseEntity.ok().body(result);`

Comment: actually exception happened `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209986/discussion-between-nonika-and-sazzad-hissain-khan).

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to create bean and deserializate this String to it.
After it you will have structured object with all benefits. (For example pretty toString method)

Comment: If you provide MWE it would be helpful

Comment: What does mean MWE? Example? restTemplate.getForObject(url, request, Foo.class)

Comment: ResponseEntity<Foo> response = restTemplate
  .exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, request, Foo.class);