# How do I get the compact/minified form of pretty-printed JSON in Java?

Tags: java, json, minify

[How do I make Jackson's build() method pretty-print its JSON output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176881/how-do-i-make-jackson-pretty-print-the-json-content-it-generates) is an example that pretty-prints the JSON string.

I need to take the pretty-printed version of JSON string and then convert it to the compact/minified form. How can it be done?

I need to convert this:

```json
{
  "one" : "AAA",
  "two" : [ "B B", "CCC" ],
  "three" : {
    "four" : "D D",
    "five" : [ "EEE", "FFF" ]
  }
}
```

to this:

```json
{"one":"AAA","two":["B B","CCC"],"three":{"four":"D D","five":["EEE","FFF"]}}
```

I tried to remove '\n', '\t', and ' ' characters; but there may be some of these characters in values so I can't do that.

What else can be done?

Comment: How about reading the pretty-printed data back into Jackson and then output it again without pretty-print enabled? See [converting a String to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591388/converting-a-string-to-json-in-java)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Jackson allows you to read from a JSON string, so read the pretty-printed string back into Jackson and then output it again with pretty-print disabled.

See [converting a String to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591388/converting-a-string-to-json-in-java).

---

#### Simple Example

```
String prettyJsonString = "{ \"Hello\" : \"world\"}";

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readValue(prettyJsonString, JsonNode.class);

System.out.println(jsonNode.toString());
```

**Requires**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You should probably use the TokenBuffer class when reading the data, that way the write will be much more efficient.

Comment: no need to put core dependency, jackson-databind automatically import jackson-core as a transitive dependency

Answer (score 9):

The safe way is to read the data using the JsonNode API and just write it out again without enabling the pretty printer.

```
ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode rootNode = m.readTree(payload);
String compressed = rootNode.toString();
```

If the object is huge, the [Streaming API](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/wiki) can help.

Using a regexp does also work if you use this pattern: `\s*\n\s*`

This doesn't create the most compact form (i.e. you will still have some spaces between elements) but it's a cheap solution if you already have the JSON as a String. The reason why this pattern is safe is that new lines are invalid in String values (they must be escaped using `\n`) so you can safely remove whitespace around them.

Comment: Would love to see an example of the raw data binding.

Answer (score 9):

With the streaming API, you can use [`JsonGenerator.copyCurrentEvent()`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonGenerator.html#copyCurrentEvent%28com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser%29) to easily re-output the token stream with whatever pretty-printing applied you want, including the default of no whitespace; this avoids buffering the entire document in memory and building a tree for the document.

```
// source and out can be streams, readers/writers, etc.
String source = "   { \"hello\" : \" world \"  }  ";
StringWriter out = new StringWriter();

JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
JsonParser parser = factory.createParser(source);
try (JsonGenerator gen = factory.createGenerator(out)) {
    while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
        gen.copyCurrentEvent(parser);
    }
}

System.out.println(out.getBuffer().toString()); // {"hello":" world "}
```

You can use the same approach to pretty-print a JSON document in a streaming fashion:

```
// reindent
gen.setPrettyPrinter(new DefaultPrettyPrinter());
```

Answer (score 7):

[Jackosn-core](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core) is one way of pretty printing json. You can read the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/12174201/432903

You can also use `org.json` library, which is a very simple but standard json lib for java. Open source code here -> [stleary/JSON-java](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java).

### [maven dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20160810</version>
</dependency>
```

### usage

```
        String payload = "{\n" +
            "  \"fact1\": \"Java is verbose.\", \n" +
            "  \"fact2\" : \"C has pointers\"\n" +
            "}";
        System.out.println(new JSONObject(payload));
```

You'll get compact json `{"fact2":"C has pointers","fact1":"Java is verbose."}` in one line.