# Custom pretty printer using Jackson library

Tags: java, json, jackson, pretty-print

I have data in a Map object and I want to print it in a json format. I tried using DefaultPrettyPrinter

```
mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(filePath, mapObject);
```

but the format is not what I expected. I am getting output like this:

```
{
  "arrVals" : ["value-1","value-2"]
}
```

I want output like this:

```
{
  "arrVals" : [
    "value-1",
    "value-2"
  ]
}
```

Comment: There is a simmilar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176881/how-do-i-make-jacksons-build-method-pretty-print-its-json-output (NOT a duplicate in my opinion) that can help you

Comment: I have seen that but it doesn't solve the problem. I need printing array values in next line.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411586/jackson-json-not-formatting-correctly/17415099

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need indentation before Array Values. You can use `indentArraysWith` method to set the `Lf2SpacesIdenter` object which will basically add a line feed followed by 2 spaces.
This might solve your problem.

```
DefaultPrettyPrinter pp = new DefaultPrettyPrinter();
pp.indentArraysWith(new Lf2SpacesIndenter());
mapper.writer(pp).writeValue(filePath, mapObject);
```

Comment: Lf2SpacesIndenter is at DefaultPrettyPrinter.Lf2SpacesIndenter
The constructor and instance field are deprecated. Use:
pp.indentArraysWith( DefaultIndenter.SYSTEM_LINEFEED_INSTANCE );