# How can I format this Json to put extra spaces and make it look readable?

Tags: java, json

```
 {"question":"Gli elementi della porta nel calcio sono pali, la
 traversa e…","includeInfo: ":false,"info: ":"info:
 ","answers":{"answerText":"Porta","correct: ":"0"}} {"answers:
 ":{"answerText":"Una palla","correct: ":"0"}} {"answers:
 ":{"answerText":"La rete","correct: ":"1"}
```

I already used `.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(j);`, but it puts some unnecessary blocks, which I don`t need.

```
I use a resultSet to extract data from my DB and that data consists of questions and answers basically, but each question has different number of answers. The point is to make a readable Json with the questions and the proper number of answers. And, finally, the problem is that the data is quite large and prerryPrinting recognise the type of my data(like boolean, String, chars) and puts it before the element. If I`m using the basic JsonObject, the data looks is shown above. Is there any other way to construct my Json?
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom pretty printer using Jackson library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18098513/custom-pretty-printer-using-jackson-library)

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: Basic org.json library

Comment: All of the prettyprinting methods puts some blocks, for example ("chars" : "Gli elementi della porta nel calcio sono pali, la traversa e…",
    "string" : "Gli elementi della porta nel calcio sono pali, la traversa e…",
    "valueType" : "STRING") How can I get rid of "String", "value", unnecessary field?

Comment: Can you post an example of the JSON formatted as you would like?

Comment: {
   "question": "How old is Madonna?",
            "includeInfo": true,
            "info": "Madonna Louise Ciccone is an American singer, songwriter, actress, and businesswoman.",
            "answers": [
                {
                    "answer": "50",
                    "correct": 0
                },
                {
                    "answer": "54",
                    "correct": 0
                },
                {
                    "answer": "56",
                    "correct": 1
                }
            ]
} I hope it is shown with spaces

Comment: Each element on a new line with spaces before

Comment: Do you need it to be readable on the browser for a human eye? if yes, then you may consider using some browser add-on to format the coming JSON, like [JSONView](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc?hl=en) for Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `JSONObject.toString(int indentFactor)` method. It takes an `int` representing your desired indent factor.

Just a warning from the [org.json java docs](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/json/JSONObject.html):

> Warning: This method assumes that the data structure is acyclical.

Code sample:

```
        String in = "{\"question\":\"Gli elementi della porta nel calcio sono pali, la  traversa e…\",\"includeInfo: \":false,\"info: \":\"info:  \",\"answers\":{\"answerText\":\"Porta\",\"correct: \":\"0\"}} {\"answers:  \":{\"answerText\":\"Una palla\",\"correct: \":\"0\"}} {\"answers:  \":{\"answerText\":\"La rete\",\"correct: \":\"1\"}";
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(in);
        System.out.println(obj.toString(4));
```

Comment: This is the closest solution to what I need, so far.

Comment: @VoicuMihaiCatalin I'm glad about that. You could consider editing your question: maybe if the explanation of your need is more detailed, you'll be able to get an even closer solution